# set alert for label in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am using the following condition to identify the crossover with fib levels. I tried to set alert condition for the below one but alerts are not getting generated.
Is there any way to set alert

```
var string trigger = na
var label lb12 = na
var line ln12 = na

if crossover(close,level12) and open < level12
    if bar_index <= firstBar + 4
        if (barstate.islast)
            lb12 := label.new(bar_index, high)
            ln12 := line.new(time + 1000 * bar_size, high, time, high, xloc.bar_time, color=color.red)
            line.delete(id=ln12[1])  
            label.delete(lb12[1]) 
 alertcondition(crossover(close,level12),title="Trigger breakout",message="trigger candile")
```

Comment: What did you try? Where is your `alertcondition()` call?

Comment: `alertcondition(crossover(close,level12),title="Trigger breakout",message="trigger candile")`

Comment: Please edit your question and add new information there. It is important to know where exactly you call this function.

Comment: Updated , i tried to add the alert condition inside the if  statement also but got the error stating that alert condition not possible under local scope, later i tried outside the if statement then i am able to load the script still alerts are not getting generated

Comment: someone please help me here

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to track if your breakout condition is true. Then later, you can use this flag to trigger the alerts.

Try something like this:

```
var string trigger = na
var label lb12 = na
var line ln12 = na
isBreakout = false

if crossover(close,level12) and open < level12
    if bar_index <= firstBar + 4
        isBreakout := true
        if (barstate.islast)
            lb12 := label.new(bar_index, high)
            ln12 := line.new(time + 1000 * bar_size, high, time, high, xloc.bar_time, color=color.red)
            line.delete(id=ln12[1])  
            label.delete(lb12[1]) 

alertcondition(isBreakout, title="Trigger breakout", message="trigger candile")
isBreakout := false // Reset flag
```

Also, you should manually set the alerts as described [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Alert_conditions.html).